# What is the space between galactic arms called?

Tags: astronomy, terminology, galaxies

Is there a term referring to space that is inside the plane of a galaxy, but not part of the center/bar/arms/spurs, etc?  What's the filler called?

The space between two spiral arms (if it isn't a spur or anything) would be called... I really feel like there should be a word for this, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 3):

You might be surprised, but it is called "inter-arm space". :)